# How to incorporate GET variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got this form

```
  <form action="http://someaffiliatelink/s1={subid}" method="post">
    <label id="text5">You must be 100 years and above to enter.</label>
    <label id="text6">Please confirm your age.</label>
    <select name="">
      <option selected="selected" value="Select Your Answer" id="text7">Select Your Answer</option>
      <option value="Select Your Answer" id="text8">I'm 100+. Let Me In.</option>
      <option value="Select Your Answer" id="text9">I'm Under 5.</option>
    </select>
    <button id="text10" class="submit-button" type="submit">CONTINUE!</button>
  </form>
```

Say a person go to http://somedomain.com/?subid=helloworld

Now I want the form submit to

http://someaffiliatelink/s1=helloworld

instead.

How do I do so using javascript.

Comment: Any reason you can't render this server-side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters